# Java 8+ Time stamp issue with OffsetDateTime

Tags: java, datetime, timestamp

I have the following block of code.

```
OffsetDateTime offset =  OffsetDateTime.parse(timestamp, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);
return String.valueOf(offset.toInstant().toEpochMilli());
```

If I parse "2020-05-01T00:00:00+05:00", I get 1588273200000 milliseconds which translates to
Your time zone: Thursday, April 30, 2020 3:00:00 PM GMT-04:00 DST
The later was obtained from a site that is specifically made for timestamps.

https://www.epochconverter.com/

The question is why am I not getting +5:00 as it was initially set? Why is java doing a double conversion to get the time in my local time zone? I would like to get the GMT timestamp.

I have tried all the possible values for DateTimeFormatter.

Comment: You are asking Java to do a double conversion, first from `OffsetDateTime` to `Instant` and next to milliseconds since the Unix/Java epoch. What was the question again, please? https://www.epochconverter.com/ tries to be kind and converts to your time zone, but also gives the GMT time (Thursday 30. April 2020 19:00:00). The results you got are correct.

Answer (score 1):

[Instant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) represents an instantaneous point on the time-line in UTC and  [Instant#toEpochMilli](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#toEpochMilli--) gives you the number of milliseconds from the epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z in UTC. This number is the same or universal across the world and is used to calculate date and time in different timezones by applying their corresponding offsets.

The time in GMT (which has the offset as +01:00) is 4 hours behind your given date-time string (which is with offset +05:00). See the output from the code given below:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dateTimeStr = "2020-05-01T00:00:00+05:00";
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateTimeStr);

        // Get LocalDateTime from the given date-time string (which is with the offset
        // as +05:00 hours)
        LocalDateTime ldt1 = odt.toLocalDateTime();
        System.out.println(ldt1);

        // Get LocalDateTime in GMT (which is with the offset as +01:00 hours)
        // corresponding to the given date-time string
        LocalDateTime ldt2 = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(odt.toInstant(), ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));
        System.out.println(ldt2);

        // Print offset of the given date-time string and that of GMT
        System.out.println(odt.getOffset());
        System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/London")).getOffset());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-05-01T00:00
2020-04-30T20:00
+05:00
+01:00
```

**Note:** Your given date-time string is already in the default format of `OffsetDateTime` and therefore you do not need to specify `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME` to parse it.

Answer (score 1):

OffsetDateTime in [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#toInstant--)

> OffsetDateTime is an immutable representation of a date-time with an
> offset. This class stores all date and time fields, to a precision of
> nanoseconds, as well as the offset from UTC/Greenwich. For example,
> the value "2nd October 2007 at 13:45.30.123456789 +02:00" can be
> stored in an OffsetDateTime.

OffsetDateTime store offset from UTC and your `1588273200000 milliseconds` is fine.
And there no difference for specific millis between two timezone. Only difference will happen when you represent them as string for specific timezone. See here, https://currentmillis.com/

Answer (score 0):

To recreate an OffsetDateTime with the +5 hours offset, you can do the following:

```
//this is your code
val timestamp = "2020-05-01T00:00:00+05:00";
val offset = OffsetDateTime.parse(timestamp, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);
val millis = offset.toInstant().toEpochMilli();

//now we go back to an OffestDateTime with 5 hours offset
val original = Instant.ofEpochMilli(millis).atOffset(ZoneOffset.ofHours(5));
println(original);
```

and that code outputs the same string as `timestamp`.

Comment: It would give the time at GMT.

Comment: I don't understand your question: "2020-05-01T00:00:00+05:00" and "April 30, 2020 3:00:00 PM GMT-04:00 DST" are the same time... In my code, change the `original` line using `ZoneOffset.ofHours(-4)` (instead of +5) and you will get 30-April-2020 15:00:00-04:00

Comment: If I try to put that in milliseconds, it goes back to 1588273200000

Comment: Yes because they are the same moment in time, so they have the same number of millis since the epoch. They are just *represented* differently.